# HTML files on SharePoint

Tags: html

We are a content provider and one of our customers wants to take one of our content packages (it's a microsite, basically) and store and launch it via Sharepoint.

Problem is, they can't house all the files and use the index.html page for some reason. So the client proposed changing the index.html file to be "index.aspx" but that worked in ie but did not work in Chrome.

In our content files, there are apparently a many javascript files that reference the HTML file and this cannot be changed.

Is there any way to just have the file set run like a normal set of html pages?

Answer (score 3):

just use an content editor webpart. And select the html file from content editor. 
Ot will easily solve ur problem I guess.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint on-prem sites allows to store HTML pages using different ways,  for example, in hive directory. Your partner should package your site as a wsp file and install on the SharePoint farm. Then, make a feature to set the home page as the file you want. That makes to have a site under SharePoint without using SharePoint features like security.

You can also store your HTML, css and JavaScript files on a SharePoint library and create some links that points to those pages, you will have to update js and css references to point to the proper files as well. Having these you are able to use some SharePoint features like security.

And, lastly, your partner can create an addin packaging all that site functionality and let the user to install it wherever she wants.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestions. Will relay to our partner!